# How to paste variable into function in controller

Tags: smarty, prestashop

I hope I type right topic. What I need to know ? From controller I have list of cms page from my shop. Then I want to get content but I don’t know how.

My controller:

```
    class ProductController extends ProductControllerCore {

    public function initContent() {
        parent::initContent();
        $cmsList = CMS::listCms();
        $this->context->smarty->assign('cmsList', $cmsList);
    }

    public function getCMSContent($cmsID){
        $cmsID = CMS::getCMSContent();
        $this->context->smarty->assign('cmsContentProduct', $cmsID);
    }

}
```

In my product.tpl file I have:

```
{$productCategory = $product->category}
            {foreach from=$cmsList item=varCMS}
                {$cmsID = $varCMS.id_cms}
                {$cmdTitle = $varCMS.meta_title}
                {if $cmdTitle == $productCategory}
                    {* get contnet from CMS*}
                {/if}
            {/foreach}
```

How to paste my cms ID to getCMSContent ?

Kind regards

Comment: If I used {Product::getCMSContent($cmsID)} the my shop is broken.

Answer (score 0):

```
    class ProductController extends ProductControllerCore {

    public function initContent() {
        parent::initContent();
        $cmsList = CMS::listCms();
        $this->context->smarty->assign('cmsList', $cmsList);
    }

    public function getCMSContent($cmsID){
        $cms = new CMS($cmsID, intval($cookie->id_lang));
        return $cms;
    }
}
```

And the .tpl file:

```
{$productCategory = $product->category}
                {foreach from=$cmsList item=varCMS}
                    {$cmsID = $varCMS.id_cms}
                    {$cmdTitle = $varCMS.meta_title}
                    {if $cmdTitle == $productCategory}
                        <section class="page-product-box">
                <h3 class="page-product-heading"></h3>
                <div class="rte"><p>{ProductController::getCMSContent($cmsID)->content[1]}</p></div>
            </section>
                    {/if}
                {/foreach}
```

This function check product category and compare with all cms page. If the same then this function display the content of CMS. It's works on PS 1.6.

Kind regards